# Host-based ssh authentication failure with Chef

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, knife

Using chef-12.1.2-1, all nodes running Centos 7.

I've setup up host based ssh authentication on my nodes and can successfully ssh without passwords between them.

I start up a chef server by doing the following:

`/opt/chef/bin/chef-zero -H <ip> -p 8889 -d`

and try to bootstrap my nodes using knife bootstrap which takes me to a password prompt:

```
[root@node]# knife bootstrap <ip> -r <role> 
Connecting to <ip> 
Failed to authenticate root - trying password auth 
Enter your password:
```

After doing some digging I found that knife uses the Ruby implementation of SSH, using the gem net-ssh-multi. I can't find specifically why this wouldn't work with host based authentication.

Why is it prompting me for a password and not using my host based authentication?

Comment: I think this question belongs to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: [[chef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef)] is pretty popular here on SO. Infrastructure-as-code is like the union of SO and SF ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try HostbasedAuthentication as an ssh flag passed into knife?

`knife bootstrap <ip> -r <role> -a HostbasedAuthentication`